# How much does the light novel of Re:Zero differ from the anime at the end of episode 21 (Subaru/Rem scene)?

Tags: re-zero

In the anime, there is a touching scene between Subaru and Rem. But according to a person who's supposedly read the light novel, the producers changed this scene.

In the light novel, Rem faked her death (she pretends as if she was dying in Subaru's arms) with the goal to hear his deepest feelings for her. Subaru really confesses his feelings for Rem and shortly after he realized that she was only playing.

Here's a link to [Amino Apps](http://aminoapps.com/page/anime/9459096/re-zero-kara-hajimeru-isekai-seikatsu-light-novel-volume-7-6-08) about the summary where I've got this information:  (it's pretty much at the end of volume 7)

Does this really happen? (somehow I just can't get rid of the feeling that this summary isn't trustworthy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the light novel and did a re-check to the wikia. Here are the differences between anime and light novel in episode 21:

- A scene where Mimi saves Subaru with her magic is cut.
- Rem's attack is added on to Mimi and Hetaro's attack to free Wilhelm.
- Subaru and Hetaro's conversation is cut.
- Crusch's speech is moved farther into the battle and an anime original scene was added to include it.
- **Rem faking her death to get Subaru to confess is cut.**
- The post Hakugei battle scene is changed to have Subaru and Crusch talk one on one instead of being with Rem and Ferris. In accordance with this, several other scenes such as Subaru and Ferris' talk is also cut.

So, based on the statements above, the scene you were talking about was not changed, but it was cut.

Comment: Do you know what kind of feelings Subaru confesses to Rem? Is it in a romantic or plain familiar/amicable way? Somehow, it's a bit confusing since he still seems to hold romantic feelings towards Emilia according to himself. He affirms this in the last episode right before Subaru runs away with the bomb. Or does this scene also only happen in the anime?

Answer (score 1):

There are translations of the scenes if you care to read them yourself.

- [Arc 3: Rem Feigning Her Death](https://remonwater.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/rezero-web-novel-translation-of-rems-proposalconversation-with-subaru-under-the-flugel-tree/)
- [Arc 3: Rem’s Proposal/Conversation With Subaru Under the Frugel Tree](https://remonwater.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/rezero-web-novel-translated-scene-of-rem-feigning-her-death/)

As to whether they're platonic or not, the scene kind of ends with Subaru leaning in for a kiss before being interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the source material from light novel was changed and/or cut in the anime due to time constraints I believe and that unfortunately includes Rem faking her death to get Subaru's love confession.